# Converting UTC 12 hour time format to indian time using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am writing an event scheduler in Mysql for generating tickets 3 hour prior to the user travel time. Mysl is installed in server where the server time is in UTC and 12 hour format with 5:30 hour difference with IST time. I have one user whose travel time is 7:30 in the morning, so i need to generate ticket for this user at 4:30 in the morning. I am getting current server time and converting to IST and comparing travel time and current converted time difference is 3 hours. But some how its failing and always ticket creating at 10 am in the morning. Below is my complete event writtent in Mysql,

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER EVENT `Auto_Generated_Ticket` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
     DECLARE UserId INT;
     DECLARE v_finished INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE GetDate DATE DEFAULT DATE(NOW());


     /*get all active user's who's tariff enddate is > today and available journeys > 0 and pass-status=4(delivered)*/
     DECLARE ActiveUserId CURSOR FOR 
       SELECT UT.user_id FROM `um.user_trs.tariff` UT
    INNER JOIN `um.user` U ON U.user_id=UT.user_id
    INNER JOIN `um.user_ps.pass` UP ON UP.user_id=UT.user_id
    INNER JOIN `ps.pass` P ON P.pass_id=UP.pass_id
    WHERE UT.end_date >=DATE(NOW()) AND UT.available_journeys > 0 AND UT.current_balance>0 AND P.status_id=4
    GROUP BY UT.user_id;

     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished=1;
     SET @GetTime= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p');
     OPEN ActiveUserId;
       get_userid:LOOP
       FETCH ActiveUserId INTO UserId;
       IF v_finished=1 THEN
        LEAVE get_userid;
        END IF;

         SET @StartTime=(SELECT RS.start_time FROM `um.user_rm.route` UR 
                INNER JOIN `rm.route_schedule` RS ON RS.route_schedule_id=UR.route_schedule_id
                WHERE UR.user_id=UserId
                ORDER BY ABS( TIMEDIFF( RS.`start_time`, TIME(CONVERT_TZ(@GetTime,'+00:00','+05:30')) ) ) LIMIT 1);

         SET @TimeDiff=(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(@StartTime,TIME(CONVERT_TZ(@GetTime,'+00:00','+05:30')))));


          /*if time difference between current time and schedule start time is 3 hours then generate ticket for the user for that particular schedule*/
         IF (@TimeDiff =3) THEN
            /*IF (@TNumber IS NULL) THEN*/
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ticket_number FROM `um.user_ts.ticket` WHERE route_id=@RouteId AND route_schedule_id=@RoutScheduleId
                   AND user_id=UserId AND DATE(date_of_issue)=@ISTDATE) THEN
             INSERT INTO `um.user_ts.ticket` 
                 (
                  `user_id`,`route_id`,`route_schedule_id`,`ticket_number`,`date_of_issue`,`is_cancelled`,
                  `amount_charged`,`user_tariff_id`,`opening_balance`,`is_auto_generated`
                 )
                VALUES
                (
                 UserId,@RouteId,@RoutScheduleId,@TicketNumber,CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'+00:00','+05:30'), 
                 FALSE,@PerJourneyCost,@UserTariffId,@TariffCurrentBalance,1
                );


           END IF;/*end of route and schedule check*/
         END IF; /*end of time difference check*/   
       END LOOP get_userid;
       CLOSE ActiveUserId;      
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Please let me know if any other way to convert time or any mistake which i am not noticing in the above query.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: It is better to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated mysql command to do so. `CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)`
See here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

From their docs:

> CONVERT_TZ() converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by
>   from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting
>   value

Maybe the warning applies to you ?

> Warning
>
> Do not use a downloadable package if your system has a zoneinfo
>   database. Use the mysql_tzinfo_to_sql utility instead. Otherwise, you
>   may cause a difference in datetime handling between MySQL and other
>   applications on your system.

I would break it down to a minimalistic example and see if this works.
Here's how I would do it to test the basics:

Simple example:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-24 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
```

So you could build a query to determine the timediff like this:

HOUR(TIMEDIFF(
  CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-24 12:00:00','GMT','MET'), 
  '2016-05-24 12:00:00'
))